# Checking Off-Diagonal Entries in a Python Conditional Loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to implement the QR algorithm to find some eigenvalues of a matrix, but I'm having some trouble putting together the loop in Python.

Basically, I have a square, invertible matrix A with off-diagonal entries, and every time I go through the loop, I want to check if these off-diagonal entries are below a certain set accuracy (e.g. 1^-6). If they are, I want to stop and give the resulting matrix. Here is what I have so far:

```
accuracy=1^-6
V=numpy.identity(4)
for x in xrange(100): 
    while i != j:
        if A[i][j]>accuracy:
            Q,R=numpy.linalg.qr(A)
            A=numpy.dot(R,Q)
            numpy.dot(V,Q)
        else:
            print "Off-diag entries below accuracy value"
            print A
```

My code doesn't work, though. It says i is not defined yet, but I'm not sure what I would define it as since it's supposed to be the row entries of the matrix A. I guess I'm just stuck with this loop.

**Edit:**

Ok, I got rid of the while loop because it was making things confusing. 
Now what I have is:

```
accuracy=1^-8
V=numpy.identity(4)
for i in xrange(0,4):
    for j in xrange(0,4):
            if A[i,j]>accuracy:
        Q,R=numpy.linalg.qr(A)
        print "This is Q:",Q
        print "This is R: ",R
        A=numpy.dot(R,Q)
        print "This is the new A where A=RQ:",A
            numpy.dot(V,Q)
            else:
                print "Stopped"

print "This is A now:"
print A
```

This is what I got for A:

```
This is A now:
[[  9.77769257e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.22862690e-08   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.00578866e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.20385489e-04]
 [  3.22862677e-08   0.00000000e+00   7.22307431e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.20385489e-04   0.00000000e+00   2.44211345e+00]]
```

What I am supposed to get is a diagonal matrix, with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. In my edited code above, I omitted checking for the off-diagonal elements because I'm not sure how to go about it. But basically, it should check whether elements not on the diagonal are smaller than the accuracy constant given above. If they are, then the loop should finish. If not, it should keep going until the off-diagonal elements really are that small. This is all to approximately get a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

`i` and `j` aren't defined before you use them in the inner loop, and their value isn't changed.

On the other hand, `x` isn't used in the outer loop.

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, and whether you need the two loops. But maybe you wanted something like:

```
accuracy=1^-6
V=numpy.identity(4)
for i in xrange(4):
    for j in xrange(4):
        if i != j:
            if A[i][j]>accuracy:
                Q,R=numpy.linalg.qr(A)
                A=numpy.dot(R,Q)
                numpy.dot(V,Q)
            else:
                print "Off-diag entries below accuracy value"
                print A
```

updated: fixed while i != j to if i != j

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but the loop doesn't end... Then I tried to break it but upon checking if it was running by including print statements within, none of the statements got printed.

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in my snippet that caused it not to end, fixed it now.